# How to set fixed colors for the different levels of a categorical variable in gt()'s data_color() function?

Tags: r, gt

I would like to set fixed colors for the levels of a categorical variable used in a gt table. Take a look at the example below. I want the level "a" always to be colored in red, "b" always to be orange, and "c" always to be colored in green, no matter if some of the levels are missing or not.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gt)

data <- tibble(
  var1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
  var2 = c("a", "b", "b", "c", "c"),
  var3 = c("a", "a", "c", "c", "c"))

  data %>% 
  gt() %>% 
  data_color(columns = c(var2, var3), method = "factor", 
             palette = c("red", "orange", "darkgreen"))
```

Comment: Yes! Good that someone double checked this. I made a mistake in my factor conversion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option which worked for me was to convert the columns to `factor`s with the levels set to include all possible options. Would have expected that the `levels=` or `domain=` arguments can be used to achieve that but wasn't able to figure out how to apply them. Perhaps I miss something obvious.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gt)

data %>%
  mutate(
    across(
      c(var2, var3),
      ~ factor(.x, levels = c("a", "b", "c"))
    )
  ) %>%
  gt() %>%
  data_color(
    columns = c(var2, var3), method = "factor",
    palette = c("red", "orange", "darkgreen")
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks guys! It worked by explicitly setting the factor levels. I knew the variable should be a factor but didn't know that I must set the levels too. It wasn't explained clearly in the package vignette. Thanks again!